# Android service behavior is different in debug mode and release mode when use sleep button, why?

Tags: android, debugging, service, sleep

I am developing an application that uses a Service as Contdown. When the user starts the countdown from the activity and the activity goes in background after the sleep button is pressed, I am using this Service to continue the countdown. When the count is finished the Service shows a notification with ringtone.

I use wait() "to count" the time in the Service. The strange behavior occurs when I use the application on a real device, but in debug mode. When Eclipse debugger is attached, the Service works well; when I test the application on the device without Eclipse debugger attached, the Service doesn't show the notification when the countdown is finished, unless the sleep button is repressed and the monitor is activated - then the notification and the ringtone are activated.

Can anyone can explain what causes this strange behavior? Maybe the issue is is related to Wake lock or a similar construct?

Answer (score 1):

> I use wait() "to count" the time in Service.

That is poor programming practice. Time elapses even without your tying up RAM to do it.

> Anyone can explaine why this strange behavior?

The device fell asleep. This is normal, and desirable, behavior, to conserve battery life. With the USB cable plugged in, the device does not need to fall asleep, and if you checked the appropriate option in Developer Options, the device specifically will *not* fall asleep while plugged in.

> Maybe is connected with Wake lock

Please do not use a `WakeLock` to keep the device awake for you to watch the clock tick by. Please use `AlarmManager` to get control when the countdown period is over. You can use a `_WAKEUP`-style alarm to arrange to wake up the device, and your `BroadcastReceiver` that gets control at that point can "launch a notification and ringtone". As a bonus, you can get rid of your service, so that your app can be better behaved on the user's device.

Answer (score 1):

`wait()` calls are not guaranteed to wait for the right amount of time if the device goes to sleep. You should use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to trigger your countdown timer instead.